# Use of setter getter from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, getter-setter, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I've already created a `CustomView(.Xib)` with it's class(.Swift).
In order to reach it's views (widgets) property I've defined several getter and setter and for now I need to call them to modify but when I make an object from the class I can't modify the properties or use `get {}` method.

It's my custom class codes of views :

```
CustomClass.Swift

@IBOutlet weak var barLbl: UILabel!
@IBDesignable class CustomControl: UIView { 
@IBInspectable var lblSetGetName : String! {
    set { barLbl.text = newValue }
    get { return barLbl.text }
}
```

And here in another view controller that I can't achieve get and set of my views :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let CustomControlObj : CustomControl!
    var lblName = CustomControlObj.lblSetGetName
    CustomControlObj.lblSetGetName = "New Txt"
}
```

Here, In another view controller class compiler says : `Constant 'CustomControlObj' used before being initialized`.

Comment: You never initialize `CustomControlObj`, you only declare it.

Comment: How should do that ? @rmaddy

Comment: Given that `CustomControl` is all setup to be done in Interface Builder, I would change `CustomControlObj` to be an outlet instead of a local variable. Then connect the outlet in Interface Builder.

Comment: @rmaddy Your are a life saver <3 .

Answer (score 1):

You can load it like this

```
let customControlObj  = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil))?[0] as! CustomControl
customControlObj.frame = view.frame
customControlObj.lblSetGetName = "New Txt"
view.addSubview(customControlObj)
```

Comment: By this code I'll get an runtime error in Appdelegate -> `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<iPlay.ViewController 0x7f9322d150a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key barImgVw.'`

Comment: This is irrelevant to the answer , but you can add this line beside the outlets of the class **ViewController** --------> **@IBOutlet weak var barImgVw:UIImageView!**

Comment: yeah I know. my @IBOutlet is working safe but it gives me error.

Comment: Added that property ?? according to the crash it doesn't exists